# Problem that the time interval of vertx.setPeriodic function decreases

Tags: java, vert.x, vert.x-webclient

It is set to send a PING to the server every 5 seconds.
Initially, pings were sent every 5 seconds.
A month has passed since the program started.
Currently, pings are being sent to the server 2-3 times per second.
There seems to be a BUG in the "vertx.setPeriodic" function.

```
long[] pID = {0};
pID[0] = vertx.setPeriodic(5000, handler -> {       
    sendHTTP2PING(mapKey, conn);
});

private void sendHTTP2PING(String mapKey, HttpConnection conn) {
    conn.ping(pingData, pong -> {
        if(pong.succeeded()) {
            localAddressPort = conn.localAddress().port();
            logger.info("[HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] RECEIVED PONG");
        } else {
            logger.info("[HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!");
            disconnectToServer(mapKey);
        }
    }).closeHandler(ch -> {
        disconnectToServer(mapKey);
    }).exceptionHandler(exh -> {
        disconnectToServer(mapKey);
    });
}
```

log file

> 2020-10-27 16:13:10 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:10 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:11 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:11 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:11 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:12 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:12 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:13 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:15 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:15 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:16 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:16 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:16 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:17 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:17 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:18 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:20 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!
>
> 2020-10-27 16:13:20 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] - [HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug, of course, and [you could open a new issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues), specifying Vert.x version and any means to reproduce it.

What I would like to point out, though, is that your code doesn't equal "print message every 5 seconds". It schedules the call every 5 seconds, yes, but it prints out only when the remove service responds, or fails to respond.
Meaning, if your remote server responds with some random delays, you'll see messages at random delays, or even out of order.

What I would suggest to try instead is to use `setTimer` instead. That way, you'll ensure that you don't create a queue of outbound requests.

```java
pID[0] = vertx.setTimer(5000, handler -> {       
    sendHTTP2PING(mapKey, conn);
});

private void sendHTTP2PING(String mapKey, HttpConnection conn) {
    conn.ping(pingData, pong -> {
        if(pong.succeeded()) {
            localAddressPort = conn.localAddress().port();
            logger.info("[HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] RECEIVED PONG");
        } else {
            logger.info("[HTTP/2 CLIENT PING] DOES NOT RECEIVED PONG...!!!");
            disconnectToServer(mapKey);
        }
        vertx.setTimer(5000, handler -> {       
            sendHTTP2PING(mapKey, conn);
        });
    }).closeHandler(ch -> {
        disconnectToServer(mapKey);
    }).exceptionHandler(exh -> {
        disconnectToServer(mapKey);
    });
}
```